# first and second partial derivative of integral of a vector norm

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, definite-integrals, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I'm not very familiar with the Leibniz rule or chain rule of differentiation. Could anyone check whether my calculations are correct?

I need to find the first and second partial derivative of the following function:

$$f(\vec x) = \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{1} \lvert\phi(\vec x(s, t))\rvert\,ds\,dt$$
$\lvert\cdot\rvert$ is the Euclidean norm, and $\vec{x} = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$ , $x_i =x_i(s,t)$ and $\phi(\vec{x}) = \{\phi_1(\vec{x})  ,  \phi_2(\vec{x}), \phi_3(\vec{x})\}$.

My calculations:
$$ \frac {\partial f(\vec x)}{\partial x_i} = 
\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{1} \ \frac{1}{\lvert\phi(\vec x)\rvert}
 \left[ \phi(\vec x)\ {\frac{\partial \phi(\vec x)}{\partial x_i}}^T \right] 
 \,ds\,dt$$

$$ \frac{\partial f(\vec x)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} = 
\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{1} 
\left[
\frac{-1}{2}\ \frac{1}{\lvert\phi(x)\rvert^3 } 
\left( \phi(\vec x)\ {\frac{\partial \phi(\vec x)}{\partial x_j}}^T \right)
\left( \phi(\vec x)\ {\frac{\partial \phi(\vec x)}{\partial x_i}}^T \right)
 \right]
+    
\frac{1}{\lvert \phi(\vec x)\rvert}
\left[
\frac {\partial \phi(\vec x)}{\partial x_j} \
 {\frac{\partial \phi(\vec x)}{\partial x_i}}^T+ \phi(\vec x)\
 {\frac{\partial \phi(\vec x)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}}^T  \right]ds\,dt$$

Comment: Won't $\|\phi(x)\|_2$ be independent of $x$?

Comment: @MichaelLee, I don't understand. could you please explain?

Comment: In the form of an equation, how are you defining $\|\phi(x)\|_2$?

Comment: @MichaelLee, $\phi(x)$ is a vector function of $\vec x$. Then I can find the $L_2$ norm. RIght?

Comment: Try writing out what the $L_2$ norm of $\phi(x)$ is as an equation. This should convince you that it won't be dependent on $x$ (assuming that $x$ is your variable of integration; if it's $s$ and $t$ and $x$ is some arbitrary function, then that's possible, but you haven't made that clear, and furthermore in this case there would be no reason to integrate in $s$ and $t$ again after already taking the $L_2$ norm in these variables).

Comment: @MichaelLee, Does above edits make sense?

Comment: You haven't answered my question. When you take the $L_2$ norm of $\phi(x(s, t))$, what is your variable of integration?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63198/discussion-between-user8153630-and-michael-lee).